# Is there any performance impact using index.ts in Typescript - Ionic App

Tags: angular, typescript, import, module, ionic2

In the standard ionic app, the project structure is like this:

```
app
pages
----page1
---------page1.ts
----page2
---------page2.ts
```

If I add an *index.ts* in the pages folder like this:

*pages/index.ts*

```
export { Page1 } from './page1';  
export { Page2 } from './page2';
```

Then in each of the pages folder, do this:

*pages/page1/index.ts*

```
export * from './page1'; 
export * from './page1.service'; //etc
```

Then if I want to import `page1` in `page2`:

```
import { Page1 } from '../'
```

Is there any performance impact doing this or is it better to reference the module directly like this everywhere:

```
import { Page1 } from '../page1/page1'
```

Hope the question is clear. Its going to be a fairly big application and I didn't to mess up this part.

Answer (score 0):

I think performance wise, there should not be any difference.
You can use either way.

I am also developing ionic2 app which is fairly large. Here I am referencing each module directly like this:

```
import { Page1 } from '../page1/page1'
```

And it works just fine.

I think it will make a difference, if you want to maintain a good code structure and usability. Usability meaning, it will be easier to reference modules by this for you and other developers.

Comment: Pretty sure this will just be eliminated by the to-JS build step.

Answer (score 0):

The there won't be any performance impact by changing the directory structure, 
but the directory structure is to make it maintainable.